# Get data from 3 table

Tags: mysql, accounting, subquery

I have three tables in my database first one is account_group, next is ledger and last one is account_receipt, 
account_group has fields group_id and group_name, and this group_id is mapped to ledger, ledger table contains fields ledger_name and group_id. and in the last table account_receipt has fields ledger_id and receipt_amount.

so what I need is I want to get receipt details when group_id is given.I cant write the query for this.any help would be appreciated.

```
schema:: 
account_group::
    id          int(11)
    group_name  varchar(60)
ledger ::
        id          int(11) 
    group_id    varchar(60)
        ledger_name     varchar(60)
account_receipt::
        id          int(11) 
        ledger_id       int(11)
    amount          float
        receipt_date     date
```

Comment: It's much easier to read and understand if you show the schema of your tables (ideally with some datas), instead of just describing them...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query. It uses JOINs to connect the various tables, column aliases and table aliases.

```
SELECT
    ag.id group_id,
    l.id ledger_id,
    l.ledger_name ledger_name
    ar.id receipt_id,
    ar.amount amount,
    ar.receipt_date receipt_date
FROM account_receipt ar
INNER JOIN ledger l ON ar.ledger_id = l.id
INNER JOIN account_group ag ON ag.id = l.group_id AND ag.id = <given group id>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Three table joining example has been given below

```
select * from Table_A A
join Table_B B on B.id=A.id
join Table_C C on C.id=A.id
```